# Button is not disabling in another activity

Tags: java, android, button, android-button

I'm beginner in android dev and i'm creating a pizza clicker game, just like cookie clicker. I created an activity for upgrades and for upgrading you need some amount of pizza like if you have 10 pizzas you can upgrade. If the amount of pizzas is equals the price the button is enabled, if not, the button is not enabled. When I click the button, the amount of pizza is decreased and the button should disable again, but it's not disabling.

Here's the first activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

public static int pizza = 0;
public static TextView pizzaContText, helpers;
public static Button add, upgrades, exit;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.makePizza);
    exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitButton);
    upgrades = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upgrades);

    pizzaContText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pizzas);
    helpers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helpers);

    pizzaContText.setText("Pizzas: " + pizza);
    pizzaContText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    pizzaContText.setTextSize(40);

    helpers.setText("Helpers: " + Upgrades.contHelper);
    helpers.setTextSize(20);
    helpers.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    upgrades.setOnClickListener(this);
    exit.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.makePizza:
            pizza++;
            pizzaContText.setText("Pizzas: " + pizza);
            pizzaContText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            pizzaContText.setTextSize(40);
            break;

        case R.id.upgrades:
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Upgrades.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case R.id.exitButton:
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

And here's the second activity (the upgrades):

```
public class Upgrades extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

public static int contHelper = 0, priceHelper = 10;
Button addHelper, back;
Handler h = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upgrades);
    initialize();


    if (MainActivity.pizza >= priceHelper){
        //ENABLES THE BUTTON
        addHelper.setEnabled(true);
    } else{
        //DISABLE THE BUTTON
        addHelper.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

private void initialize() {
    addHelper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addHelper);
    addHelper.setText("Helper: " + priceHelper + " pizzas");
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);

    addHelper.setOnClickListener(this);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.addHelper:
            MainActivity.pizza-=priceHelper;
            addHelper.setText("Helper: " + priceHelper + " pizzas");
            priceHelper+=4;
            contHelper++;

            //Auto clicks the make pizza button every 1 sec
            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MainActivity.add.performClick();
                    h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            };
            h.postDelayed(r, 1000);
            break;

        case R.id.back:
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: which line of code disables your button , please identify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use static objects.. Is the worst thing you could do.. Use bundle to send your variable

```
Intent activity = new Intent(this, Upgrades.class);
activity.putExtra("pizza", pizza);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your Upgrades activity use

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int pizza = extras.getInt("pizza");
```

And check for nulls and that you send the correct things.

Comment: I did what you said but the app stop working when I try to go to upgrades activity

Comment: Doesen't matter. Android life cycle could be different from phone to phone. Static is the worst thing. But do as you want..